# Removing border separation in navigation bar elements

Tags: css

I've built a simple center aligned navigation bar for my website. However, the borders of the elements in the navigation bar aren't perfectly overlapping, giving a disjointed look. Here's what I mean:

[image]

Notice the *double-borders* for each link. Note that even I remove one of the borders, the hover effect still reveals the imperfection:

[image]

How can I fix this via creating borders that perfectly overlap?

---

Here's the code:

```css
ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff9933;
    font-size:90%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    ul.navbar li {
        margin: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
        border-left: 1px solid #ffb366;
    }


    ul.navbar li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.navbar li a:hover {
        background-color: #e67300;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>New Account</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Old Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set both the `li` and the `a` element's `display` value to `inline-block` it will fix the issue you have:

```css
/* navigation bar*/

ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff9933;
    font-size:90%;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.navbar li {
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffb366;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #e67300;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will also allow you to `hover` the entire item in the menu (and not only part of it).

## Another option

(without changing the HTML structure) is to change the font-size of the `ul` element (and set font-size to the `li`):

```
l.navbar {
    font-size: 1px;
}

ul.navbar li {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Working example:

```css
/* navigation bar*/

ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff9933;
    font-size: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.navbar li {
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffb366;
    font-size: 14px;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #e67300;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Highly peculiarly, when I run your snippet here, it works correctly. But in my project, it does nothing, except for *increasing the height* of the entire navigation bar :/

Comment: Without looking at the entire *problem* - mostly every solution might not be good :) Can you create an example in snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Included a snippet in the ques

Comment: In my example the you have `</li><li>` (without the space and the line-break between every two `li` elements :)

Comment: Check the update in my answer, there is also a solution without changing the html structure.

Comment: Yes, I did. Also reading this article: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ I think the first answer you gave - one where <li> elements should be in the same line, is probably going to be the one with the widest cross-browser compatibility, right?

Comment: Both options are ok :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, inline-block elements have a some surrounding 'space', by default:

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

```css
ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff9933;
    font-size:90%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    ul.navbar li {
        margin: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
          box-sizing:border-box;
          margin-left:-4px;
     
    }
ul.navbar li:first-child {
   border-left: 1px solid #ffb366;
}

    ul.navbar li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    ul.navbar li a:hover {
        background-color: #e67300;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>New Account</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Old Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, keep just right border, and place left border to first li....

Comment: Thanks checking it out, and also, great reference!

Answer (score 1):

Add only `border-left` to all `li` items. And for the last one add `border-right` as well

```
ul.navbar li {
    margin: auto;
    display: inline;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffb366;
}

ul.navbar li:last-child, ul.navbar li:hover{
     border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
}
```

Update: The issue was in the font-size of the `ul`

```
ul.navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ff9933;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

ul.navbar li {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding:0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffb366;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
    width:auto;
}
```

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/8j5It4jlrZRgTMxsArAu?p=preview

Comment: Well it takes care of the double-borders, but the hover effect still reveals the imperfection.

Comment: Ah not quite. On hover, double borders actually appear for all elements. The last element works perfectly though.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8j5It4jlrZRgTMxsArAu?p=preview Check this, the font-size inside the ul seems to be the problem.